# From a python script, change user, set environment and run a couple of commands

Tags: python, shell

I need to run a python script that changes user, sets a enviroment variable and executes a command and return the output.

1.) The way I am currently doing this is I am creating a shell script that does this for me:

tmpshell.sh

```
su - grid -c "echo +ASM1 | . oraenv; asmcmd volinfo -a"
```

The command fails because the environment is not being set.

2.) The second way I tried was by changing user is python script itself and then creating the shell script.

tmp.py

```
os.system('su - grid')
TMPFILE="/tmp/tmpfile.sh"
filehandle=open(TMPFILE,'w')
filehandle.write('+ASM1|. oraenv')
filehandle.write('asmcmd volinfo -a')
filehandle.close()
os.chmmod(TMPFILE,0755)
```

Here the problem is that the python script changes the user but the rest of the script doesn't run until I enter exit.

OUTPUT

```
[root@odadev1 oakvmclientlib]# python test.py
[grid@odadev1 ~]$ exit

[root@odadev1 oakvmclientlib]#
```

Any suggestions/better ways to do this ??

p.s.(edit) ". oraenv" is for setting the environment and +ASM1 is the environment variable it expects.

Comment: Try out the fabric awesomeness, it suits your usecase pretty well .. http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/

Comment: this would be amazing...but the system I am working for has only basic python modules and that too python version 2.4.x >.<

Comment: If `oraenv` is basically a custom wrapper around `env` or at least functions similarly, then you might want to try changing the sh line slightly: `"echo +ASM1| oraenv asmcmd volinfo -a"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$ sudo -u grid sh -c ". oraenv; echo +ASM1|asmcmd volinfo -a"
```

This will launch a shell as user `grid`, set up the environment in it and execute the command. I'm not sure what the second part of your command does, though - I suspect you want to pipe `+ASM1` into the standard input of `asmcmd`, but you haven't given enough context to be sure.

Comment: ok well, ". oraenv" is for setting the environment and +ASM1 is the environment variable it expects

Comment: Then try `$ sudo -u grid sh -c "echo +ASM1|./oraenv; asmcmd volinfo -a"`. Make sure oraenv is executable and starts with a shebang line.